# Can not parse space inside a bash variable

Tags: bash, variables, character, space

I can not use spaces instead of "_" characters on this bash command:

```
text=-annotate\ +540+8\ \"July_9_2020_newspaper\"
magick -quality 100 out.png $text out1.png
```

I tried "\\ " => Error.

Any ideas ?

Thanks of your possible answer ;)

Comment: Use an array instead of just a variable to store the options/arguments.

Comment: `options=(-annotate +540+8  "July_9_2020_newspaper"); magick -quality 100 out.png  "${options[@]}" out1.png`

Comment: Hello Jetchisel , my question is to replace _ chars by spaces... i want that imagemagick creates "July 9 2020 newspaper" sentence. Actually i mandatory need to use "_" char to create a word/number separator but i want to use space instead ;)

Comment: Ah, ok, then `text=${text//_/  }`, but still  the `${options[@]}` can be `"${options[@]//_/ }"`

Comment: @Jetchisel maybe OP's question just how to quote a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing arguments with spaces via list in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262077/passing-arguments-with-spaces-via-list-in-bash)

Comment: replace `_` with non-breaking whitespace, maybe it will work with `[[:blank:]]`

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to store multiple arguments to your command:

```sh
text=(-annotate +540+8 'July 9 2020 newspaper')
magick -quality 100 out.png "${text[@]}" out1.png
```

Comment: Yep ! Works well ! Thanks a lot !